# Jquery apply fx for each

Tags: jquery

I want to set a random opacity-animation duration for each of some elements. My idea was to get the index of the element then multiply it with a random number and apply this to the duration. But this applies the same amont of time for the whole thing... What have I done wrong?!

Here is my code :

```
var numLow       = 100,
    numHigh      = 3000,
    adjustedHigh = (parseFloat(numHigh) - parseFloat(numLow)) + 1,
    numRand      = Math.floor(Math.random()*adjustedHigh) + parseFloat(numLow);

$('ul li').each(function(index, value) { 
    var numbb = index + 1 * numRand; 
    $(this).css('opacity','0');
    $(this).animate({
        opacity: 1
    },numbb);
});
```

Here is the link to it : http://jsfiddle.net/moabi/PCqMC/

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same random number inside the loop.  So, Generate random number inside the loop !

Working code below:-

```
$('ul li').each(function(index, value) {
      var numRand = Math.floor(Math.random()*adjustedHigh) + parseFloat(numLow);
        var numbb = index * numRand;
        $(this).css('opacity','0');

         $(this).animate({opacity: 1},numbb);
});
```

Remaining code should be as it is :)

code modified after Jasper's opinion that numbb should modified with increasing index 1,2,3 etc.

Comment: thank you, but i though that my var numbb would do the trick, if we take a number: 100 and multiply it with the index (1,2,3...) this should do it no ?

Comment: I believe the question was how to increment the duration of the animation by the index of the element. The problem code is `var numbb = index + 1 * numRand;` which multiplies the random number by one before adding to the index, which only gives a difference of one millisecond per index.

Comment: @Jasper, If this is so, var numbb=index*numRand. will do the stuff.

Comment: @Umesh The reason to add one is because the first index is zero so the first duration would be zero.

Comment: @Jasper, ohh Sorry. It missed from me. Will the (index+1) behave right here ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('ul li').each(function(index, value) { 
        var numbb = (index + 1) * numRand;
        $(this).css('opacity', 0).animate({
           opacity: 1
        }, numbb);
    });
```

Note that I added parenthesis around the `index + 1` so they will be added before multiplying. Also I chained the `.css()` and `.animate()` calls so `$(this)` only had to be created once.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PCqMC/6/

**UPDATE**

On a side-note, using `for()` loops properly is a big performance increase over `.each()`:

```
    var $LIs = $('ul li');
    for (var i = 0, len = $LIs.length; i < len; i++) {
        var numbb = (i + 1) * numRand;
        $LIs.eq(i).css('opacity', 0).animate({
           opacity: 1
        }, numbb);
    });
```

A JSPerf for demonstration: http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loops/2

Comment: thx, but i only want the timing to random, i want all elements to end at 1 in opacity

Comment: @moabi Try the update, I misunderstood the first time: http://jsfiddle.net/PCqMC/6/

Comment: @moabi You need to have the `index + 1` in parenthesis so they are added before the multiplication happens. Order of operations is Multiplication then addition.

Comment: @moabi Additionally check out the update I just posted about `for` loops, they will increase the speed of your function greatly: http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loops/2

Answer (score 0):

You need some parens around one of your calculations to get variation.  The multiplication by `numRand` was happening first and then adding index so you were getting essentially no variation.  Adding the parens gives you much more variation as you intended:

```
var numLow = 100,
   numHigh = 3000,
   adjustedHigh = (parseFloat(numHigh) - parseFloat(numLow)) + 1,
   numRand = Math.floor(Math.random()*adjustedHigh) + parseFloat(numLow);

$('ul li').each(function(index, value) { 
    var numbb = (index + 1) * numRand; 
    $(this).css('opacity','0');
    $(this).animate({
        opacity: 1
    },numbb);
});
```

In jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/YRTU5/

I would also suggest using `.fadeIn()` as a shortcut for fading in opacity.